# How can I perform a segue from LoginViewController to HomeViewController without the ability to go back to the LoginViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue

I'm developing an iOS app in Objective-C with Xcode 6. After my user logs in, my app performs a show (push) segue to the HomeViewController. On the HomeViewController the user has the ability to navigate back to the LoginViewController. Is it possible to have a push segue from the LoginViewController to the HomeViewController without the ability to navigate back to the LoginViewController? Or is my only option a modal segue?

Comment: Are you pushing the loginViewControler? You can present it and once the user logged in pop it out

Comment: Yeah, atleast I think so. How would I the loginVC out?

Comment: thanks for your help guys, but I decided to hide the back button! Works like a charm too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your initial view controller to be the HomeViewController and then use a modal segue to the LoginViewController if the app has never been used before. I just use a boolean to check whether the user has logged in before. You will want to save this in NSUserDefaults so that the next time the user opens the app, the LoginViewController will not be presented.

```
    userReturned = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("userReturnedCheck")
    if userReturned == false {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("setupView", sender: self)
    }
```

If you have done it this way then there shouldn't be a back button so the user has no way of returning to the login screen.

Comment: I'm using Parse for my backend & User management etc, so I don't really know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

#### You should use two UINavigationViewControllers.

1. Your Login is embedded in a `UINavigationViewController` with `NavigationBarHidden` activated.
2. Your `HomeController` is embedded in another UINavigationViewController.
3. On login push the second UINavigationViewControllers with your HomeController on to the first UINavigationViewController.

That way your HomeController can push other views which can have a back button, and you don't have to hassle with hide and unhide the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I CTRL drag from HomeVC to LoginVC for the segue?

Comment: I think you drag from your LoginVC to HomeVC and let segue push by default.